# Why does TweenLite.to and hitTestObject not work?

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code:

```
stop();
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.greensock.TweenLite

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // Add the button click

    function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {
        TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
    }

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);

    function einde1(e:Event){
        if(auto.hitTestObject(stopauto)){
            var myTween=TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
            myTween.kill();     //here code for tween killing
            trace("works")
            //
            auto.x = 241;
            auto.y = 375;
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1)
        }
    }
```

and I want that if auto hits stopauto, auto goes to

```
auto.x = 241;
auto.y = 375;
```

it does the trace but it doesn't go to the x and y what I want it to go

Answer (score 0):

You have two tweens, one of them is never killed. I guess it simple goes on and overrides your x/y for the final car destination.

```
//tween one
function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {
  TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
}

//tween two
function einde1(e:Event){
  if(auto.hitTestObject(stopauto)){
    var myTween=TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
    myTween.kill();     //here code for tween killing
    //REST OF YOUR CODE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fygo is absolutely correct. In your `enterframe` handler, instead of getting a reference to the `Tween` you started in the `click` handler, you are in fact creating a new `Tween` which you then kill immediately, rather than the original `Tween` which continues to execute.

I think the following will fix it:

```
// ... Rest of your code

function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // start the tween on mouse click
    TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);

function einde1(e:Event){
    if(auto.hitTestObject(stopauto)){

        // Objects have collided so stop the tween
        TweenLite.killTweensOf(auto);    

        // Place the object somewhere else
        auto.x = 241;
        auto.y = 375;

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Is it giving you a line number?

Comment: It is what I needed, so the tween goes to the x and y what I want but it continues with tweening

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add myTween = TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6}); for that error but it still continues tweening

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if that gives you what you want.

Comment: no it is still not working you might want to see my whole code I have placed in a fiddle althought it is in as3, http://jsfiddle.net/kQfAp/

Comment: I don't have time to debug that just now I'm afraid. One thing though, you should really only have one enterframe running. Also, you shouldn't be referencing both TweenLite and TweenMax. TweenLite is just a subset of TweenMax so if you've imported TweenMax because you need some of its features, you don't need to import TweenLite at all.

Comment: can you please look at it if you have time I'm really struggeling with it and I see no way to get an solution I have made an fla with an simplyfied version of my project so you can see what I want https://www.dropbox.com/s/bywncjn21t1c4gz/stackoverflowtest.fla

Comment: I can't open the fla and the code is too badly formatted for me to follow without significant effort. Try and refactor so that you have one animation loop (one enterframe) and see if you can make a simplified (well formatted) version that demonstrates the problem. You can then post a new question and I'll be happy to look at that.

Comment: thanks for you're interest but I have fixed my problem already